# jPlayer not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery-plugins

Hi Ive used jPlayer plugin and its working in chrome but not in IE and Firefox
can anyone help me   to get this thing to work, here is the working demo ,
the music should be automatically playing,  http://goo.gl/9RNIr
I already ask support at the jplayer plugin forum about this, but nothing came out good.

I check already the plugin documentation but I cant still able to fix it.
 http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/

any suggestion?

-edit-

the Fix is, I correct the url swf file , case close, this topic is ok already.
Silly Me.

Comment: @Neil , ok, I have now edit  it, thanks