# Jplayer plugin not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am using Jplyer plugin on my web page using the following code

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function(event) {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "Demo/demo/Demo.mp3" }).jPlayer("play");
    },            
    swfPath: "Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3",
    volume: 1,
    wmode: "window",
    solution: "html,flash",
    error: function(event) {
        alert(event.jPlayer.error.mes);      
    }
});
```

its playing fine in all browser but I have found that when some permissions are blocked in browser its not playing the audio file and also not showing the alert Message can any one solve this problem so that at least jplayer shows the alert when permissions are blocked. or any other way to detect permission using javascript.

Comment: Is this helpful to u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359331/jplayer-not-working-in-firefox-and-ie

Comment: You'll prob still need flash as FF doesn't support native playing of mp3 format :(